# How do I pass parts of my Knockout viewmodel to a component when loading everything via require.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, components

I'm getting started with Knockout.js components. I need to pass a component a part of my viewmodel as its data to use.

When the viewmodel is global, this is simple

```
<my-component params="myGlobalViewModel.dataSubSet"></my-component>
```

How do I do this when the viewmodel is loaded via require.js, and there is no access to this from global scope?

At the moment I additionally store a reference to the viewmodel in a global variable and then use this. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewmodel is made "global" (from the HTML bindings' perspective) when you call `ko.applyBindings()` on it. If `dataSubSet` is a member of your viewmodel, just do

```
<my-component params="dataSubSet"></my-component>
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought to just try this.